# How to release camera after activity ends in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an application that requires to scan a QR code and click pictures, but sometimes it so happens that the camera application crashes and it says that the Android Camera has stopped working and the device needs to be restarted for proper functioning.

I want to be able to release the camera from my activity itself to avoid it crashing later in any case.
Help needed!

CODE FOR SCANNING:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
       intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
       startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }catch(Exception e){
         // ERROR
    }
} //End of onCreate

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
   if (requestCode == 0){
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         showPass(contents);
      }
      else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
         showFail();
      } 
   } // End of If
} //End of onActivityResult
```

CODE FOR CLICKING PICTURE :

```
public void takephoto(View v){
     Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        //some action.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put Below code in your `onDestroy` method of your activity:

```
protected void onDestroy(){

if(camera!=null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }


}
```

If you are using separate Preview class then add below code in that:

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if(camera!=null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What if I am simply passing an intent to the camera and the scan application? How do I do the same then?

Comment: Please do it in onPause method of your Activity, its better to release it there.

Comment: camera is object of Camera.

Comment: Please see my code and tell me where I can create an object for the camera when im directly passing the intent? Some code will be VERY useful.

Comment: protected void onDestroy

Comment: @Riser why you mentioned to put release code in preview class rather than in activity?