# Bug recording videos android

Tags: android, video, service, background, camera

I'm trying to reocord many videos of 30 seconds in background but, after 20 or 30 videos my service wich is stoping and launching the process to record go slowly.

I have try with a service in the same process and the problem was the same.

My video handler:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    isRunning = true;
    idAlerta = Common.getStorage().getString(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, "");
    videoCount = 1;
    mIntentRecorder = new Intent(VideoHandlerService.this, RecorderService.class);
    mIntentSend = new Intent(VideoHandlerService.this, SendVideoService.class);
    updateVideoTime();
    mIntentRecorder.putExtra(Constants.VIDEO_TIME, videoTime);
    mIntentRecorder.putExtra(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, idAlerta);
    mIntentRecorder.putExtra(Constants.COUNT_ALERTA, videoCount);
    startService(mIntentRecorder);
    newVideo();
}
public void newVideo() {
    Common.log("new Video");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            videoCount++;
            startNewVideo();
            if (videoCount == 2)
                sendVideo(4000);
        }
    }, videoTime + 2000);

}


public void startNewVideo() {
    final Intent intentRecorder = new Intent(VideoHandlerService.this, RecorderService.class);
    intentRecorder.putExtra(Constants.VIDEO_TIME, videoTime);
    Common.log("idAlerta " + idAlerta);
    intentRecorder.putExtra(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, idAlerta);
    intentRecorder.putExtra(Constants.COUNT_ALERTA, videoCount);
    stopService(intentRecorder);
    if (Common.getStorage().getBoolean(Constants.RECORDER_ACTIVE, false)) {
        if (Common.getStorage().getString(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, "") != null && Common.getStorage().getString(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, "").length() > 0) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Common.log("Start service recorder");
                    startService(intentRecorder);
                    newVideo();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    } else
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startNewVideo();
            }
        }, 5000);
}
```

And this is the process to record:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Common.log("onStartCommand");
    if (intent != null && ((Common.getStorage().getString(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, "") != null && Common.getStorage().getString(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE, "").length() > 0))) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        mLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        //Cojo Información del videohandler
        Common.log("Intent distinto de null");
        mVideoTime = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.VIDEO_TIME, 15000);
        mIdAlerta = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.ID_ALERTA_SERVICE);
        mVideoCount = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.COUNT_ALERTA, 1);
        Common.log("Video time" + mVideoTime);
        Common.getStorage().putBoolean(Constants.RECORDER_ACTIVE, true);
        initRecording();
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void initRecording() {
    Common.log("INIT RECORDING IN");
    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    windowManager.addView(surfaceView, mLayoutParams);
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    Common.log("INIT RECORDING OUT");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Common.log("onDestroy Video");
    PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper = PreferenceHelper.newInstance(RecorderService.this, Constants.USER_PREFERENCES);
    preferenceHelper.setBoolean(Constants.IS_RECORDING, false);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Common.log("error setPrevieCallback" + (e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "sin mensaje"));
    }

    try {
        muteSounds(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Common.log(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        Common.log("media recorder stop");
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        Common.log("media recorder reset");
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        Common.log("media recorder release");
        mediaRecorder.release();
        Common.log("media camera lock");
        camera.lock();
        Common.log("media camera release");
        camera.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Common.log("onDestroy Video");
    Common.getStorage().putBoolean(Constants.RECORDER_ACTIVE, false);
    RecorderService.super.onDestroy();
    System.exit(0);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mSurfaceHolder = holder;
    Common.log("SurfaceCreated");
    try {
        try {
            muteSounds(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Common.log(e.getMessage());
        }
        Common.log("CAMERA OPEN 1");
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(1);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Common.log(e.getMessage());
        }
        Common.log("CAMERA OPEN 2");

        ///////////////////////////
        mCamCoderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        mCamCoderProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP;
        mCamCoderProfile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        ///////////////////////////

        startRecorder();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage() != null)
            Common.log(e.getMessage());
    }
}


public void muteSounds(boolean mute) {
    Common.log("MUTE SOUNDS IN");
    AudioManager mgr = ((AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (mute) {
            mgr.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            mgr.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            mgr.adjustVolume(AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE, 0);
        } else {
            mgr.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
            mgr.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        }
    } else {
        mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, mute);
        mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mute);
        if (mute) {
            mOlderVolumen = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
        } else
            mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, mOlderVolumen, 0);

        mgr.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
    }
    Common.log("MUTE SOUNDS OUT");
}


public void startRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    camera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(mCamCoderProfile);
    videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
            "wbunker_" + mIdAlerta + "_" + mVideoCount + ".mp4");
    Common.log("Video rercorder name file " + videoRecording);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getPath());
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    try {
        Common.log("mediaRecorder prepare");
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        Common.log("mediaRecorder prepare");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Common.log("mediaRecorder start");
    mediaRecorder.start();
    Common.log("mediaRecorder start");
    Common.log("Estoy grabando macho");
}
```

When I try to stop the service the services stops, but the camera isn't released even killing the app. Can someone help me?? thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to add `camera = null;` after `camera.release();`. It might solve the problem. Here more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705487/how-to-release-camera-after-activity-ends-in-android

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried it, anyway the main problem isn't releasing and taking the camera, the main problem is the video stops recording by itself, without error or exception, just stops, like if the camera was frozen

Comment: You should test it on many devices in order to get better perspective of your problem. From my experience one camera can behave/run different then another.

Comment: Thanks Nativ, you are right, I have test in some device and it works fine in many of them, however in others I have this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the key was use PowerManager, if you are going to use it, don't forget to release it!

```
private fun lock() {
    log("lock")
    var powerManager: PowerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    powerWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "WakeLock-Manager")
    powerWakeLock.acquire()

    var wifiManger: WifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    wifiWakeLock = wifiManger.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "WifiLock-Manger")
    wifiWakeLock.acquire()
    log("lock")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onDestroy() method of your service replace the `camera.lock()` with `camera.unLock()` and in the startRecorder() method replace the `camera.unLock()` with `camera.lock()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need to call unlock to start recording... I'm going to try without calling lock to rlease the camera, but i think it isn't the problem...

Comment: Check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#lock() That could work as it is not needed to lock afterwards.