# Preventing other camera apps from using the camera when my app is using it

Tags: android, android-camera

Will it be possible to prevent other camera app from using the camera while my app is using it, at least until the duration of my video recording is completed?

1. If yes, how can I achieve it?
2. If no, is there any event I can listen to to know if other camera app has accessed the camera?

What's happening is that the camera instance is being taken from my app and no video is being fed to the recorded file, only audio.

Comment: only 1 app at a time can use the camera. there is no multi app processing is my guess

Comment: that is the reason why you release the camera in onStop() and onDestroy() https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705813/6142219