# Zxing barcode scanner is not working after restarting the app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-permissions, zxing

I have created a barcode scanner with Zxing library. Once I click the scan button I am getting data from a rest endpoint. Everything works fine when I install the app on my device. It works even onBackPressed. But when I restart the app and click the scan button nothing happens and I dont even get any error or something helpful at my logs..!I realised that when I close the app and go to the info of the app on my device I see that the camera permission is turned on as it should.. but if I turn off the permission and open the app again I see the request permission dialogue again.. I choose "allow" and the camera opens..! I have tried so many suggestions that I read here but I havent managed to solve the issue.

On my ScanCodeActivity:

```
        Intent intent =  new Intent(ScanCodeActivity.this, TimelineActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("barcode", result.getText());
        startActivity(intent);

        onBackPressed();
    } 

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

        }
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        scannerView.startCamera(mCameraId);


    }
```

On MainActivity:

```
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }



@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode,
                                             @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                             @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super
                .onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
                        permissions,
                        grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Camera Permission Granted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Camera Permission Denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }


        }

        FloatingActionButton myFavBtn = findViewById(R.id.myFavBtn);
        myFavBtn.setOnClickListener(

                this::onClick);
    }


    private void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ScanCodeActivity.class));
}
```

Part of my manifest.xml:

```
 <activity android:name=".ui.ScanCodeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.TimelineActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.SlideActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

To give you the general view.. I have Onboarding screens which appears on the first view of the app after the installation..! Then on the main activity there is the scan button where all the main functionalities begin! Not sure if I should give you more details!!! I would appreciate it if you could give me a hint on how to deal with this issue!!! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: are you managing the camera properly? you should release camera in `onPause` of your activity

Comment: @Bhargav Hi.. thanks for the response! If you mean If I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705487/how-to-release-camera-after-activity-ends-in-android then, yes I have followed this suggestion! Not sure if I did it well but I tried!!!

Comment: are there any error shown in logcat?

Comment: @Henry cant see any..!!!